# Would this question be suitable for MO?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I have asked [What are some efficient ways to keep a note of results of a paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/147426/what-are-some-efficient-ways-to-keep-a-note-of-results-of-a-paper) in Academia SE.

> Would this question be suitable for MO?
>
> Is this better suited in MO than academia?

Comment: Since you are asking in general, no. As written, the question is not specific to mathematics.  If for some reason you are dissatisfied with the answers on Academia (they look fine to me), you can try a modified version specific to mathematics. Update this post with the new version and get feedback before trying it on MathOverflow.  Gerhard "Better Safe Than Downvoted, Closed" Paseman, 2020.04.09.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Can you please help me to make it suitable for MO other than saying "this is specific to mathematics"...

Comment: I'll think on it. However, it may take a few days.  Gerhard "Got Some Other Stuff Happenin'" Paseman, 2020.04.09.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman :D ok.. I will try to make some changes hoping to fit this in MO...

Comment: Now the question was posted on the main site: [What are some efficient ways to keep a note of results when reading a research article in mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/357160) (Although there is one close vote at the moment and the question is [in the review queue](https://mathoverflow.net/review/close/129838).)

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that the question has also entered the HNQ list: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/70737/2020/4/12 https://mathoverflow.net/posts/357160/revisions

Comment: @MartinSleziak thanks for the links